# Route53 routing issue DNS address could not be found

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns

Hello I have two domains registered on Route53, `www.sample.com` and `sample.com`

Right now `www.sample.com`'s A record is pointing to an elastic ip that is bound to an EC2 (Using Django + Gunicorn + Nginx). www.sample.com website works perfectly fine so I try to reroute sample.com's A record to the same ip, but I keep getting the issue `DNS address could not be found.` Anyone know why?

Do I have to change the `nginx` configuration file to be listening to `sample.com` as well?

Here is the configuration file

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.sample.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.sample.com
    # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/sample_com/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/sample_com/sample_com.key;


    # side note: only use TLS since SSLv2 and SSLv3 have had recent vulnerabilities
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    root /home/ubuntu/sample_Landing_page/;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/sample_Landing_page/static/static_root/;
        expires 365d;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass    
      http://unix:/home/ubuntu/sample_Landing_page/sample_Landing.sock;
    }
```

}

Comment: You asked this an hour ago... what about now? Is it working, now?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot sorry I tried to see if I posted this question already, but I didn't see anything

Comment: No, sorry, misunderstanding -- I posted my comment one hour after you asked the question, so I was asking if the behavior had changed over the hour, since I assumed you were seeing the 900 second negative- cache ttl.

Comment: @sqlbot No but I did figure something out. I put all 8 nameservers under the domain name. (Since each route 53 hosted url comes with 4 name servers). It seemed to fix it momentarily and then all of a sudden the website the did not work for both www.sample.com and sample.com

Comment: Oh, okay, now I think I see what you're doing wrong.  You only need **one** hosted zone in Route 53 for "example.com."  If you created a second one for "www.example.com." that's (except for advanced configurations) pretty much wrong but it explains why your workaround somewhat worked.  In the "example.com" hosted zone, just create a second resource record, this one for the host "www" with the correct values... then just use the name servers assigned to the "example.com" hosted zone.  The "www.example.com" hosted zone can (later) be deleted.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that makes more sense!

Comment: @user3281743 Make sure you also point the A record on Route53 to the ip `www.sample.com`